# Binding CommandBinding to other command

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have custom command ViewModel.DeleteItems. ViewModel uses as DataContext for DataGrid.
DeleteItems is binded to context menu and works fine.

I want to invoke this command via keyboard "Del". 
I can use

```
<CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" ... />
```

but I want to bind ApplicationCOmmands.Delete command to my command without hardcode (I don't want to subscribe on CommandBinding.Executed and run DeleteItems manually). How to bind application command to my custom command to datagrid only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a KeyBinding to fire off your command when the 'Del' key is pressed, e.g.:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Del" Command="{Binding DeleteItems}" />
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

You shouldn't need to do anything with ApplicationCommands.Delete to get this behaviour.